# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when using scan - Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have this Lambda function connected to an API. All the routes work except for the ***GET /items*** which should return all items in the DynamoDB table. However, I get the following error:

*"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"*

I followed this tutorial from the AWS Developer Guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-dynamo-db.html#http-api-dynamo-db-create-table

In the tutorial they use ***scan*** to retrieve all items from the table. However, when I use it, it doesn't work:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };

  try {
    let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "GET /items":
        body = await dynamo.scan({
            TableName: "users"
          })
          .promise();
        break;
      case "PUT /signIn":
        await dynamo
          .update({
            TableName: "users",
            Key: {
              UserId: requestJSON.UserId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set SignedInAt = :a, IsSignedIn = :b, SignedOutAt = :c",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":a": new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
              ":b": true,
              ":c": ""
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `User ${requestJSON.UserId} has been signed in.`;
        break;
      case "PUT /signOut":
        await dynamo
          .update({
            TableName: "users",
            Key: {
              UserId: requestJSON.UserId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set SignedOutAt = :a, IsSignedIn = :b",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":a": new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
              ":b": false,
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `User ${requestJSON.UserId} has been signed in.`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  }
  finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

Logs:

[image]

Comment: Add a `console.log(event.body);` before `let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);` to check the data

Comment: It says Undefined :( Added logs above

Comment: That's exactly what the first error message says: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`. You are trying to parse `undefined` as JSON and that's not valid. Now you have to find out why it's undefined. How do you call it? Do you send a POST request with JSON body?

Comment: I send a GET request "curl -v https://myaws.com/items"

Comment: `event.body` is the body of your request. You have to send a request with a body containing JSON data otherwise `JSON.parse(event.body)` will fail.

Comment: Ahhhhh such a silly mistake. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to parse an empty body when doing a GET request

So, now I am only parsing the body in the PUT requests:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
  let body;
  let requestJSON;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };

  try {
    console.log(event.body);

    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "GET /items":
        body = await dynamo.scan({
            TableName: "users"
          })
          .promise();
        break;
      case "PUT /signIn":
        requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo
          .update({
            TableName: "users",
            Key: {
              UserId: requestJSON.UserId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set SignedInAt = :a, IsSignedIn = :b, SignedOutAt = :c",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":a": new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
              ":b": true,
              ":c": ""
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `User ${requestJSON.UserId} has been signed in.`;
        break;
      case "PUT /signOut":
        requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo
          .update({
            TableName: "users",
            Key: {
              UserId: requestJSON.UserId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set SignedOutAt = :a, IsSignedIn = :b",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":a": new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
              ":b": false,
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `User ${requestJSON.UserId} has been signed in.`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  }
  finally {
    console.log(event.body);
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```